# ggplot2lend for sf-objects

Tags: r, vector, sf, sp, ggplot2

I wanted to make a simple plot of four `sf`-objects which don't contain much more than the `sfc`-column and some postal-code information.

The `sf`-objects have the names `level 1-4` and `plz`. What I would like to have is a simple legend next to my map just showing the names of the objects `(level 1-4) and plz` and their matching colours.

It seems like a task which would be so easy in any desktop-gis, but I'd really like to do it in `R`. My code so far looks like this and produced the follwing figure.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = level3, fill = fil.a) +
  geom_sf(data = level2, fill = fil.b) +
  geom_sf(data = level1, fill = fil.c) +
  geom_sf(data = plz, fill = "red") +
  coord_sf()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to pass the parameter `"show.legend = 'polygon'"` to geom_sf(); since you are not "mapping" a variable to the polygon's fill, but using 4 geom_sf() calls, you have to adjust `scale_fill_manual` to refer to the colors and polygons, first referring them on the geom_sf call:

```
geom_sf(data = level3, aes(fill = "A"), alpha = .5, 
          show.legend = "polygon", inherit.aes = F) +
geom_sf(data = level2, aes(fill = "B"), alpha = .5, 
          show.legend = "polygon", inherit.aes = F) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("A" = "red", "B" = "green"), 
                    labels = c("level3", "level2"), name = "the_levels")
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! I'll give it a shot tomorrow!

Comment: thanks a lot:) It worked pretty good. But do you have any idea, how I could add another layer with the legend-label depending on one of the column-names. In this case the `plz`-layer has a column labeled `plz`. And I would like to add "plz" to my legend.

Comment: the way ggplot works is mapping variables to geoms, if you want to see a legend with plz values you should map it to aes(fill = plz), it may be good if you convert it to character or factor (i'm guessing it's postleitzahl), otherwise ggplot will use a continuous scale with min and max values

Comment: thanks a lot! Helped a lot again. I hope in some time I can also give some helpful advices here